# iphone / objective-c how to check to see if a textfield is empty

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have a typical textfield in an iphone app, and in ViewWillAppear I would like to do a little logic using the text in the text field.

If txtField.text is empty, I would like the next textfield, txtField2 to be selected for typing.

I am trying to achieve this through :

```
if (txtField.text != @"") [txtField2 becomeFirstResponder];
```

but after some testing, txtField.text (whilst empty), will still not register as being equal to @"" 
What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks to all the excellent answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective c checking whether text field is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173679/objective-c-checking-whether-text-field-is-empty)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you compare two pointer variables you actually compare the addresses in memory these two variables point to. The only case such expression is true is when you have two variables pointing to one object (and therefore to the very same address in memory).

To compare objects the common approach is to use `isEqual:` defined in `NSObject`. Such classes as `NSNumber`, `NSString` have additional comparison methods named `isEqualToNumber:`, `isEqualToString:` and so on. Here's an example for your very situation:

```
if ([txtField.text isEqualToString:@""]) [txtField2 becomeFirstResponder];
```

If you want to do something if a `NSString` is in fact not empty use `!` symbol to reverse the expression's meaning. Here's an example:

```
if (![txtField.text isEqualToString:@""]) [txtField2 becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Ivan, thanks that works nicely. Is there something like an inverse to isEqualToString, like a isnotEqualToString??

Comment: How about:

if ( ! [txtField.text isEqualToString:@""]) [txtField2 becomeFirstResponder];

Comment: Yes, there's a way to do this. Not using a `isNotEqualTo:` method though. :) Added an example.

Answer (score 9):

You must check either:

```
if (txtField.text.length != 0)
```

or

```
if ([txtField.text isEqualToString:@""])
```

Writing your way: `(txtField.text != @"")` you in fact compare `pointers` to string and not their actual string values.

Comment: I've fired a quick answer first and then added some explaining... :) Checkin length is another good way though. Especially because zero int value is treated as false. `if (!txtField.text.length)` is probably the 'shortest' approach.

Answer (score 3):

You must also check for nil

```
if([textfield.text isEqualToString:@""] || textfield.text== nil )
```

Only if the user clicks textfield you can check with isEqualToString else the textfield will be in the nil so its better you check for both the cases.

All the best

Comment: `textfield.text== nil` was what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We already have inbuilt method that return boolean value that indicates whether the text-entry objects has any text or not.
Check that simple Solution with link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25726765/3647325